# Set all instances of Exp[-x_] to zero?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

To simplify a huge expression efficiently, which involves a variable in a bunch of exponential functions going to infinity, I have tried to substitute

```
/.Exp[-x_]->0
```

where my intention was to set to zero any exponential function featuring a minus sign in front of an arbitrary function.
Unfortunately this substitution had no effect.

How can I do what I intend? Please note, `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` functions involving any `ComplexityFunction` are not an option, since they take forever to evaluate.

**EDIT**

On a similar note, I noticed that oftentimes expressions of the same power appear as multipliers in numerator and denominator, like in the following example

$$\frac{a f_{1}+af_2}{(a f_3+af_4)f_5}$$

still the $a$ does not cancel out automatically. Is there a command to explicitly look for such cancellations and carry them out without attempting any other simplifications? I tried `PowerExpand`, `Expand` and `ExpandAll`. None of them work like this.

Comment: Can you provide small snippet of your expression in which your substitution doesn't work? Because it works fine for me here.

Comment: Do you have complex exponents? Because Mathematica distinguish between real and complex -1. So maybe you need to change your pattern to `Exp[(-I | -1) x_]`

Comment: `Exp[- a ] /. Exp[- x_] :> 0` gives `0` but `Exp[-4 a ] /. Exp[- x_] :> 0` gives `Exp[-4 a ]` and `Exp[-4 a ] /. Exp[(-I | -1) x_] :> 0` gives `Exp[-4 a ]`

Comment: On your second matter, this will do the trick: `/. x_/y_ :> Collect[x, a]/Collect[y, a]`

Comment: Try this `/. Exp[n_?Negative x_] :> 0`

Comment: Perfect! This works, thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question, try letting _mma_ know that `a` isn't zero: `Simplify[(a f1 + a f2)/((a f3 + a f4) f5), a != 0]`

Answer (score 3):

Since this has been bumped by Community, I'll post this in the hopes that either @swish will also post it and take credit, or at least @Kagaratsch will accept this so it won't be left unanswered:

> Try this `/. Exp[n_?Negative x_] :> 0` – swish Apr 24 at 23:00

Answer (score 2):

This should work
    Exp[x_] /; x < 0 :> 0

Sticking a negative in front of a pattern variable will not accomplish what you want.

Comment: OP said that there is variable inside exponent, Mathematica generally can't say whether it's positive or not.

Comment: Exactly, swish. Evaluating `Exp[-a] /. Exp[x_] /; x < 0 :> 0` gives `E^-a`