# Simplifying an exponent using a constant rule

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How do I use mathematica to simplify an exponent by breaking it up into its constituents and setting one of them equal to a constant?

For instance,

```
E^(k - 1/x)
```

would become

```
E^(k) * E^(1/x)
```

which I could then simplify to a using

```
 /.E^(k)->a
```

Comment: Look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44625/how-can-i-separate-two-parts-of-power-of-exponential-functions)

Comment: You could do: `E^(k - 1/x) /. k -> Log[a]`